# How to convert laravel form delete into string to use it on return controller?

Tags: laravel

I have delete form but I can't use directly on blade cause I am using datatable and it just there to put the code of the form.

This is the code of delete that I want to copy

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

and I want to put/swap in the red circled image below cause `<a href="'.route('admin.users.destroy', $user->id).'"` used **GET** and not **DELETE** method.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use the ajax call instead of call it through the link you can ajax call as below and it will DELETE resource.and then refresh the datatable

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/admin/users/4',
    type: 'DELETE',  // user.destroy
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
        // refresh the datatable
    }
});
```